# Show Code map in Visual Studio fails

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, code-map

Currently I am working with big application with over 50+ projects and I wanted to generate class diagram for it. I know that VS provides that function so I tried to generate such code map, but then this happened :

> X.dll: Assembly cannot be
>   loaded: $DIR\X.dll
>   Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am kinda new to this stuff , but I want to have more global view of the application. So I need to generate such map.Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a bug.

To workaround it, try to select projects from Solution Explorer and drag them to an empty code map. You may want to avoid dragging the X project.

What sort of project is X.dll?

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work still it still shows the aforementioned error plus the interesting fact that once I try to generate code map for one project  - assembly could not be found(despite the fact that it has been rebuilt successfully) and next time I try another class the error stays from the previous try.Anyway, I realized that class diagram would be also helpful for me and I managed to find workaround, but this still stays like bug or idk.

Comment: Are you trying it with the new ASP.NET project?

Comment: No.. I am trying it with the solution I mentioned above.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what sort of project causes problem. Is it a simple class library, a console app, a test project, a packaging project etc?